# GStreamer transcode audio to AAC

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, video-encoding

I have a RTSP stream that I am re-streaming to HLS using GStreamer like so:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=rtsp://admin:1234@192.168.1.20:554/Streaming/channels/101  ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux  ! hlssink location="D:\\wamp\\www\\stream\\%06d.ts" playlist-location="D:\\wamp\\www\\stream\\play.m3u8" target-duration=5
```

The RTSP stream has video encoded with H.264 and raw audio (pcm_ulaw). My goal is to encode the audio into AAC so that the HLS supports it. What would be the correct sequence to place `! audioconvert ! voaacenc` commands into the pipeline to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have another branch between the RTSP source and the MPEGTS muxer. Something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=rtsp://admin:1234@192.168.1.20:554/Streaming/channels/101 name=rtsp ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! hlssink location="D:\\wamp\\www\\stream\\%06d.ts" playlist-location="D:\\wamp\\www\\stream\\play.m3u8" target-duration=5 rtsp. ! queue ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! mux.
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the rtppcmudepay module which as I understand de-payloads the rtsp stream content. The problem I am facing with this solution however, is that after 15-20 minutes of running, the produced HLS stream plays all the frames of the video as fast as it can download them - with no regard to timestamps. During times like these, in ffmpeg, I would generate the timestamps manually on the receiving end of the RTSP stream. Does GStreamer have a similar plugin that ignores the timestamps of the RTSP stream and generates them independently?

Comment: Why would such a thing happen after 10-15 minutes of playtime? Is that an issue on sender or receiver side? Are the timestamps verified to be broken? Is the RTSP stream live or on demand? I guess one would need some more detailed info what may be wrong in the first place or else it would be just guess work.

Comment: Well the audio PTS is indeed broken and right now it seems to be a vendor related problem. The stream is coming from Hikvision NVR and is indeed live. I am considering switching to GStreamer from FFmpeg and when using FFmpeg I would force it to generate timestamps on the go. Was wondering if there was a similar function in GStreamer.

Comment: There usually is a `do-timestamp` property on source elements. In your case it should be the `rtspsrc`. When enabled it should timestamp buffers to the current clock when they are processed. Since `rtspsrc` is a bin it may be that this option is exposed to one of its child elements though. In that case you need to write a real application to set the property on these elements.